# ROS2 Humble packages for Ubuntu 22.04 - what is the perception package?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I've tried searches for documentation on the package but whilst I can `sudo apt install -y ros-humble-perception` or load it via docker as "ros-humble-perception" I didn't find any documentation to explain what it is apart from a mention on the humble release, [ROS 2 Humble Hawksbill Released!](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-2-humble-hawksbill-released/25729/8)

It appears to have added packages over base but not include simulation or full desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper reference is the [ROS Enhancement Proposals (REPs)](https://ros.org/reps/rep-0000.html) which provide a concise technical specification for various things related to ROS.
There you can find a [document](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2001.html) describing the different ROS 2 variants. It says

> The perception variant includes packages commonly used for perception capabilities.

and as you can see it is only available from `Humble Hawksbill`.
Thus the `ros-humble-perception` variant contains following packages:

```
- perception:
    extends:  [ros_base]
    packages: [image_common, image_pipeline, image_transport_plugins,
               laser_filters, laser_geometry, perception_pcl,
               vision_opencv]
```

including `ros_base` that is defined as

```
- ros_base:
    extends:  [ros_core]
    packages: [geometry2, kdl_parser, robot_state_publisher,
               rosbag2, urdf]
```

and `ros_core` with

```
- ros_core:
    packages: [ament_cmake, ament_cmake_auto, ament_cmake_gmock,
               ament_cmake_gtest, ament_cmake_pytest,
               ament_cmake_ros, ament_index_cpp,
               ament_index_python, ament_lint_auto,
               ament_lint_common, class_loader, common_interfaces,
               launch, launch_ros, launch_testing,
               launch_testing_ament_cmake, launch_testing_ros,
               launch_xml, launch_yaml, pluginlib, rcl_lifecycle,
               rclcpp, rclcpp_action, rclcpp_lifecycle, rclpy,
               ros2cli_common_extensions, ros2launch,
               ros_environment, rosidl_default_generators,
               rosidl_default_runtime, sros2, sros2_cmake]
    And at least one of the following rmw_implementation:
    - Fast-RTPS: [Fast-CDR, Fast-RTPS, rmw_fastrtps]
    - CycloneDDS: [cyclonedds, rmw_cyclonedds]
    - Connext: [rmw_connextdds]
```

As you can see it doesn't contain any packages needed for a "desktop experience" like `rviz2`.
Therefore you need to install the largest package via `sudo apt install -y ros-humble-desktop-full` which contains everything that is officially supplied for ROS 2. (Gazebo must be installed separately, see [their instructions](https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/install_ubuntu))

```
- desktop_full:
    extends:  [desktop]
    packages: [perception, simulation, ros_ign_gazebo_demos]
```

Comment: Thanks - the point is I don't want the full desktop but wanted to know what else was available in perception.  Thanks for your update!

Answer (score 1):

Looking around online, I found [this page](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ros-programming-building/9781788627436/90bbd7f7-c946-424e-bc60-52d5ced93fa6.xhtml), which says (in part):

> Installing ROS perception
> We are going to install a single package called perception, which is a meta package of ROS containing all the perception related packages such as OpenCV, PCL, and so on.
>
> In ROS Jade
>
> `$ sudo apt-get install ros-jade-perception`
>
> In ROS Indigo
>
> `$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-perception`

This looks like the same command you've posted; `sudo apt install -y ros-humble-perception`, just for a different ROS release.

Looking around some more, I found [this Github repo](https://github.com/ros-perception), which seems to be as described in the article.